# RecursionError at /logout maximum recursion depth exceeded in django

Tags: python, django

> I just try to make a logout and redirect to home page with but it show error i'm getting what exactly  is going  wrong in code
> my `views.py` file

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate ,logout
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

> 

Comment: Your recursive function has no base case to terminate the recursion.

Comment: @quamrana: it was not meant to be recursive I think: see the import at the top, it is simply a name clash.

Answer (score 6):

Your `logout` view calls itself. This is because although you import a `logout` function, since you defined another one in your module, and thus you *override* the existing one.

You can import this with an alias:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout as auth_logout

def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```